# Finding the closest agent

Tags: netlogo

I want to find the closest agent, For example, if I have two breeds foxes and rabbits. How to find the closest rabbit for each fox. I've come up with the following code which stores the distances in a list from each of the foxes to a subset of rabbits in a particular radius.

I am wondering if there is a better and/or a simpler way to do this netlogo?

```
breed [rabbits rabbit]
breed [foxes fox]

foxes-own [closest-rabbit]

to setup
  clear-all

  create-rabbits 10
  create-foxes 2

   ask rabbits[
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor
      set color white
   ]

   ask foxes[
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color orange
  ]

 end

to go

  ask foxes[
    let rabbits-in-range rabbits in-radius 10
    let dist-list []
    let rabbit-list []

    ask rabbits-in-range[
      set dist-list lput distance myself dist-list
      set rabbit-list lput self rabbit-list

      let min-dist-idx position (min dist-list) dist-list
      set closest-rabbit item min-dist-idx rabbit-list
    ]
      ]  
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with something like this?

`ask turtles [ show min-one-of other turtles [distance myself] ]`

In a more general form

`ask <agent_set> [ <function> min-one-of <agent_set> [distance myself] ]`

In your case would be `ask foxes [ set closest-rabbit min-one-of rabbits [distance myself] ]`

```
breed [rabbits rabbit]
breed [foxes fox]

foxes-own [closest-rabbit]

to setup
  clear-all

  create-rabbits 10
  create-foxes 2

   ask rabbits[
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor
      set color white
   ]

   ask foxes[
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color orange
  ]

 end

to go

  ask foxes[
    show min-one-of rabbits [distance myself]
    set closest-rabbit min-one-of rabbits [distance myself]
    face closest-rabbit
      ]  
end
```

You can also check this other related questions
[How to find the closest turtle(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55439869/how-to-find-the-closest-turtles/)
[Minimum distance between turtles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989632/minimum-distance-between-turtles)